# c++ Injected DLL vars getting corrupted

Tags: c++, corruption, dll-injection, detours

I'm currently trying to add some functionality to a basic server application by injecting a DLL and detouring several functions and I'm having a problem with a stored IP address getting corrupted in-between 2 calls.

First I detour 'accept' and parse some values then enter them into a connection class and add it to a list.

Accept detour function:

```
std::list<Connection*> ConnectionsList;
SOCKET WINAPI MyAccept(SOCKET s, sockaddr *addr, int *addrlen)
{
    ...  
    ConnectionsList.push_back(new Connection(ClientSocket, ipstr));
    ...
}
```

connection class:

```
SOCKET s;
char * ipAddress;
char * playerName;
Connection::Connection(SOCKET sock, char * address)
{
    s = sock;
    ipAddress = address;
}
```

[image: start]

I've also detoured 'closesocket' at which point I'd like to remove the socket from the list of connections. If I breakpoint on this function the IP address appears to be corrupted.

[image: end]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Does it matter that s has changed from 296 to 292?

Answer (score 0):

`ipAddress = address;` will just copy the pointer. If something else changes what it points to, you will be in trouble.

Since this is C++ it might be safest to use a `std::string`.

```
std::string ipAdreess;
...
ipAddress = address;
```

Otherwise, `stdcpy` into a buffer big enough.

BTW, what deletes all the `Connection*` from the list?

Answer (score 0):

try to protect your `ConnectionList` etc static/global variable with a lock.